# How do I pass parameters of a function when it is passed in calling of another function?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

How do I access variables and matrices declared dynamically  in main () in runner function.
I passed them as a parameter in runner but I am not sure if it is correct because i would have to pass runner in pthread_create function call. Will I have to give all parameters I passed in runner while passing it into runner ? How do I do it ?

```
main() {
        int  m, n, p, q
        int **a, **b, **c;
    ... // dynamically allocating first, second and multiply matrices and taking values    
           // m , n , p , q from user or a file.
    ...
r= pthread_create(threads[i], NULL, runner, (void*) &rows[i]);} // should I specify the                
  // parameters of runner in it ?

 void *runner (int **a, int **b, int **c, int m, int n, int p ) // is it right ???
 { 
        .... using all parameters
pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

A thread function only gets a single argument from pthreads, a `void *`:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

The way to solve this is to define a `struct`, instantiate it and initialize it with the desired values, then pass a pointer to the structure to [`pthread_create()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).

This pointer is the `void *arg` in the prototype above. The manual page says:

> The new thread starts execution by invoking `start_routine()`; `arg` is passed as the
>          sole argument of `start_routine()`.

Comment: additionally, in your struct you can simply hold a pointer to your data, not a copy of the whole matrix itself, since it is dynamically created in main.

Comment: Thanks , I understood it , I shall try to implement it